# Is is possible to create directory at root path in kernel module?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am trying to create a directory at rootpath, e.g. `/my_own_dir/`.
Here's what I do:

```
struct file *fp = filp_open("/my_own_dir/",O_DIRECTORY|O_CREAT, 0755);
```

The `.ko` can be compiled. However, when I insmod .ko the terminal just froze.
Neither was the directory created nor the mod seemed to be inserted.

So my question is, is it possible to create such a directory? If so, what's wrong with my method?

I'm using a Ubuntu 18.04 with Kernel version 5.11.0.

Comment: What's the extra '/' on the end for?

Comment: @stark I think '/' indicates that it is a path instead of a file?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to symlink the source files into the bin directory and dynamically generate a new MakeFile in the bin directory. This allows all build files to be cleaned up easily since the dynamic Makefile can always just be recreated.

```
INCLUDE=include
SOURCE=src
TARGET=mymodule
OUTPUT=bin
EXPORT=package

SOURCES=$(wildcard $(SOURCE)/*.c)

# Depends on bin/include bin/*.c and bin/Makefile
all: $(OUTPUT)/$(INCLUDE) $(subst $(SOURCE),$(OUTPUT),$(SOURCES)) $(OUTPUT)/Makefile
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD)/$(OUTPUT) modules

# Create a symlink from src to bin
$(OUTPUT)/%: $(SOURCE)/%
    ln -s ../$< $@

# Generate a Makefile with the needed obj-m and mymodule-objs set
$(OUTPUT)/Makefile:
    echo "obj-m += $(TARGET).o\n$(TARGET)-objs := $(subst $(TARGET).o,, $(subst .c,.o,$(subst $(SOURCE)/,,$(SOURCES))))" > $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(OUTPUT)
    mkdir $(OUTPUT)
```

If you are building inside the kernel tree you can use the O variable:

```
make O=/path/to/mydir
```

If you are compiling outside the kernel tree (module, or any other kind of program) you need to change your Makefile to output in a different directory. Here a little example of a Makefile rule which output in the MY_DIR directory:

```
$(MY_DIR)/test: test.c
    gcc -o $@ $<
```

and then write:

```
$ make MY_DIR=/path/to/build/directory
```

Or a workaround:

Create a sub-directory with/for every arch name (e.g. "debug_64").
Under "debug_64": create symbolic link of all .c and .h files. Keeping the same structure.
Copy the makefile to "debug_64" and set the right flags for 64 Debug build, e.g.

```
ccflags-y := -DCRONO_DEBUG_ENABLED 
ccflags-y += -I$(src)/../../../lib/include 
KBUILD_AFLAGS += -march=x86_64
```

Remember to set the relative directories paths to one level down, e.g. ../inc will be ../../inc.
Repeat the same for every arch/profile. Now we have one source code, different folders, and different make files. By the way, creating profiles inside make files for kernel module build is not an easy job, so, I preferred to create a copy of makefile for every arch.